# how to add a ressource in a headTag within xpage?

Tags: javascript, devexpress, xpages, lotus-notes

how can i add "polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.fr" to a xp:headTag ?

I tried this code but i get this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`.

This is the code that i used :

```
<xp:headTag tagName="script">
    <xp:this.attributes>
        <xp:parameter name="type" value="text/javascript" />
        <xp:parameter name="src" value="Dx/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.fr" />
    </xp:this.attributes>
</xp:headTag>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domino does not understand the first query parameter "features" so add the `open` parameter that Domino understands and then the `features` parameter afterwards:

```
<xp:headTag tagName="script">
    <xp:this.attributes>
        <xp:parameter name="type" value="text/javascript" />
        <xp:parameter name="src" value="Dx/polyfill.min.js?open&features=Intl.~locale.fr" />
    </xp:this.attributes>
</xp:headTag>
```